# Не могу разобраться с vector < unque_ptr <T>>

Tags: c++, указатели, vector

Есть класс, в котором есть поле вектора из unique_ptr  (`Animals` - тоже класс), а так же методы чтения и записи в файл этого вектора класса. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
class Hendler {
private:
char* input;
char* output;
std::vector <std::unique_ptr <ModelObject>> *  Animals;
std::vector <std::unique_ptr <Event>> * E;
public:
Hendler(char* in, char* out, std::vector <std::unique_ptr <ModelObject> > *  A, std::vector <std::unique_ptr <Event> > * Ev) :
    input(in), output(out), Animals(A), E(Ev) {};
void inputing()
{
    std::fstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(input);
    coord p, v;
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr <ModelObject> > Animals;
    // some code
    for (int i = 1; i <= D; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> p.x >> p.y >> p.z >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
        Animals.emplace_back(new Dragonfly(p, v, DS));
    }
    inputFile.close();
}

void outputing()
{
//some code 
        for (int i = 0; i < Animals->size(); ++i) {
            switch ((*Animals)[i]->get_type()) {
            case dragonfly:
                out << (*Animals)[i]->get_position().x
                    << ' ' << (*Animals)[i]->get_position().y
                    << ' ' << (*Animals)[i]->get_position().z
                    << ' ' << (*Animals)[i]->get_vector().x
                    << ' '
                    << (*Animals)[i]->get_vector().y << ' '
                    << (*Animals)[i]->get_vector().z << ' '
                    << '\n';
                break;
//some code
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr <ModelObject>> Animals;
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr <Event> > Events;
    Hendler HendlerFile(argv[1],argv[2], &Animals, &Events);
    HendlerFile.inputing();
    //Model Mod(&Animals, &Events);
    //HendlerFile.set_N(Mod.modulating(HendlerFile.get_N()));


    HendlerFile.outputing();
    return 0;
}
```

Но после выполнения мейна, выходной файл пруст... Понимаю, что передача в класс `Handler` вектора происходит не правильно, но как правильно это сделать - ума не приложу.. З.Ы. меняться должен именно вектор из `main`.

Comment: Попробуйте привести [mcve]. В текущем виде Ваша проблема не совсем ясна.

Comment: Ответ дать не успел, опередили, так что дам комментарий - не делайте эти фокусы с `get_type()` и многоэтажными `switch`. Для того и придуманы классы и наследование, чтоб такое вот не городить...

Answer (score 1):

В функции inputting у вас содается локальный vector, в который сохраняются измененния, а после выхода из функции он разрушается.

Comment: Спасибо большое)) Глупо как-то получилось..

Answer (score 1):

Данное объявление вектора в функции-члене класса `inputing`

```
void inputing()
{
    std::fstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(input);
    coord p, v;
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr <ModelObject> > Animals;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

является объявлением локальной переменной, для которой будет вызван деструктор при завершении работы функции.  Член данных `Animals` самого класса, объявленный как

```
std::vector <std::unique_ptr <ModelObject>> *  Animals;
```

при этом никак не изменяется.

Кроме того совершенно непонятно, почему вы объявили этот член данных как указатель на вектор вместо самого объекта вектора.